# Pass service/init.d name to Ansible handler as variable

Tags: ansible

New to Ansible and was considering the following creation of services on the fly and how best to manage this.  I have described below how this doesn't work, but hopefully its enough to describe the problem.

Any pointers appreciated.  Thanks.

I'm using a template file to deploy a bunch of near identical application servers.  During the deployment of the application servers, a corresponding init script is placed using the variable:`

```
/etc/init.d/{{ application_instance }}`
```

Next I'd like to enable and ensure its started:

```
 name: be sure app_xyz is running and enabled
  service: name={{ application_instance }} state=started enabled=yes
```

Further on I'd like to call a restart of the the application when configuration files are updated:

```
- name: be sure app_xyz is configured
  template: src=xyz.conf dest=/opt/application/{{ application_server }}.conf
  notify:
    - restart {{ application_server }}
```

With the handler looking like this:

```
- name: restart {{ application_server }}
  service: name={{ application_server }} state=restarted
```

Comment: Could you please specify what precisely does not work? Is the handler not being called? Or what is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a dynamical handler name for it. What about a static handler name:

```
# handler
- name: restart application server
  service: name={{ application_server }} state=restarted

# task
- name: be sure app_xyz is configured
  template: src=xyz.conf dest=/opt/application/{{ application_server }}.conf
  notify:
    - restart application server
  service: name={{ application_server }} state=restarted
```

Comment: This makes sense not using variable for task handler name.  I was close but the cigar goes to you! Thanks.